# EF sorting & paging - slow as ordered twice?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a simple entity, and I have 100,000 of them in my SQL Sever 2012 database:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to show these in a grid, paged as 100,000 is far too many to show on one screen (and not very efficient).  The grid should allow sorting and filtering - obviously all 3 of these operations are best done on the server, and EF should translate these.

So, lets get the second page of 500 sorted by Field1:

```
var items = context.Entities.OrderBy(e => e.Field1).Skip(500).Take(500);
```

When this query is executed, it takes **12 seconds**!  So I dug into it and found it's translated as below:

```
SELECT TOP (500) [Extent1].[Id]     AS [Id],
                 [Extent1].[Field1] AS [Field1],
                 [Extent1].[Field2] AS [Field2]               
FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[Id]     AS [Id],
               [Extent1].[Field1] AS [Field1],
               [Extent1].[Field2] AS [Field2],
               row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Field1] ASC) AS [row_number]
        FROM   [dbo].[Costs] AS [Extent1]) AS [Extent1]
WHERE  [Extent1].[row_number] > 500
ORDER  BY [Extent1].[Field1] ASC
```

Surely this is being sorted twice?  I'm no SQL expert, but the sub-query orders by Field1 and assigns this order to row_number.  Then we take the TOP 500 row_numbers over 500 to get up to 500 rows for page 2.  We don't need to order the results by Field1 again.

If I take out the final `ORDER BY [Extent1].[Field1] ASC`, the query results seem to be the same and the execution time drops to a circa 150 milliseconds.

So, obviously 150ms is preferable to 12s - is there anything I'm doing wrong?  Is there anything I can do to fix this?

**Update**

The query plan is the same for both.  The only difference on the tooltip for the Sort is 'Actual Number of Rows' of 4,604 for the 12s query and 1,134 for the 150ms query.  I would add that this is generated data from a fixed list of 15 words (for this test) - i.e. Field1 contains 1 of 15 values, so there are essentially 15 groups of 6,666 rows.

[image: Query Plan]

([click for larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVxGA.png))

[SQL Server 2012 backup](http://london.csmager.net/StackExample.zip)

Comment: If it wasn't a ordered a second time then SQL Server would be free to return you records by `row_number` 501, 600, 502, 601, 503... even 12,300 ("give me 500 rows whose `row_number` is greater than 500") and you asked for them as `OrderBy(e => e.Field1)`.

Comment: What you posted is a typical paging query. Any problems you encounter are almost certainly due to a lack of indexing. The query means nothing without its execution plan. The `ORDER BY` string doesn't mean the server will perform a sort each time it encounters it. The server will check for existing indexes and use them to calculate ranking and select the rows to return. I expect you don't have the proper indexes on the paging field (ie Field1) which forces the server to do a full table scan and order, before selecting the required rows.

Comment: @ta.speot.is - I see what you're saying.  The sub-query sets the row_number as the index of the row as ordered by Field1.  Empirically, this query is returned in row order - is this just coincidence, is it not guaranteed?

Comment: I'm surprised that taking out the final ORDER BY results in a performance increase. SQL Server will fold the two ORDER BY's to one physical sort. Even if it was sorting twice why would the query become 100 times slower instead of 2 times. That doesn't make sense. Post both execution plans as images.

Comment: @CharlesMager: If you don't have an order by clause then there is no requirement to order by anything. OFten it will happen to be what you want (as in this case) because SQL just happens to have the data sorted and it isn't going to make an effort to unsort it. Sometimes though a lack of order by will make a difference. It all depends on how the DB is storing things internally. And for the record I too am surprised that removing that final sort is such a problem but have n oinsight into why this might be.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far guys.  I've worked out this is definitely a SQL question rather than an EF question, and I'm no SQL expert!  I updated to add the Execution Plan & some info. I think the repeated values are significant: I've generated 100,000 items with unique data, and both queries are essentially the same speed. **Actual Number of Rows** is around 1,100 for both (it varies each execution).

Comment: This is a case that I have not seen before. If you create a self-contained repro that I can execute in a fresh database I'll try to debug this (include some basic test data). On the other hand, a quick fix would be to have the appropriate index defined. I got the impression that you do not wish to go that way (?).

Comment: Open to suggestions on indexing - if you got the impression I don't want to go that way, it'd only be out of ignorance!  I'll create a repro and stick a link to the database backup.  It should only be a few meg.  It's semi-resolved in that the repeating data is not as likely in the app this spike is intended for, but I am very intrigued to find out what's going on regardless!

Comment: @usr link to backup added to question.  The posted query with/without the final ORDER BY should replicate the results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to a bug/idiosyncrasy in SQL Server when TOP and Gather Streams are combined. **An index will fix it**, as will disabling parallelism (globally, or for this user, or for the query). The clue was that Gather Streams spilled to tempdb which is an exceedingly rare condition. http://web.archive.org/web/20180220120719/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/05/03/parallel-row-goals-gone-rogue.aspx This is 500 level stuff.

Note, that you can't leave out the final `ORDER BY` because this makes the order of the results undefined.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem because of doing order on a large and **not indexed** column.

**Please make sure that you do Indexing for that column.**

Anyway the `order by` clause would be better with not `nvarchar` values